# Facebook redirection issue in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9

Before iOS9, a Facebook post could successfully redirect an user to an installed app via short URL (like bet365://). Now, in iOS 9, bet365:// gives invalid link. From Safari it redirects fine, but not from Facebook browser. This is just an example, there are other apps that can't be opened from FB.

What do I need to do in order to open an installed iOS app from a Facebook post (in iOS9)?

PS: I understood that now, in iOS9, if Myapp1 wants to open Myapp2, it will need to populate info.plist with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>url_to_Myapp2</string>
</array>
```

but it's strage to belive that Facebook will have to do the same with the apps he wants to open.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes you need to make in your plist and add a few urls to whitelist Facebook urls. Try adding all of them. It should work then.

[Facebook iOS 9 integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood my question.
please read again, I want reserve of your answer(from Facebook browser to app)!

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could go about achieving the same:

**1. Use a platform like [Branch](https://branch.io/) or [DeepLink.me](http://deeplink.me/)**

Use links generated by these platforms which will be opened in Safari and then redirected to your app.

**2. Facebook App Links**

This is the deeplinking solution provided by Facebook itself. Instead of generating static app url scheme links, you should generate applinks for sharing in Facebook. These can then redirect to your app or even the app store page if the app is not installed.

**3. Support Universal Links in iOS 9**

You can have iOS recognize universal links for your application. These will be in the form of `http://yourWebsite/path/to/content` and will result in your app being opened directly.

From the documentation:

> Universal links let iOS 9 users open your app when they tap links to
>   your website within WKWebView and UIWebView views and Safari pages, in
>   addition to links that result in a call to openURL:, such as those
>   that occur in Mail, Messages, and other apps.

Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) on how to configure the same.

I would suggest configuring all of the above for your application, as it will provide various ways for you to direct users directly to your app, each suitable for certain situations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
For 
1) Not prefer to use New platform
2) How to embed custom Ad ID for each ad?
3) Do I make universal links for all Ad?

Comment: 2) I am quite sure Facebook Ads already use FB App Links, so you just need to configure the same. 3) Please explain the nature of links you want to generate.